# How to Manually Add Auth Headers to FireStore Requests

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to add auth headers to a `getDocs()`, manually?

```
async function getCities() {
  const citiesCol = collection(db, "cities");
  const citySnapshot = await getDocs(citiesCol);
  const cityList = citySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
  return cityList;
}
```

Something like:

```
  const citySnapshot = await getDocs(citiesCol,{
   headers:{Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
});
```

Assuming I have a valid access token.

I haven't been able to find anything like this in the docs(auth headers are automatically added to requests under the hood after you go through the auth flow in Firebase), so I'm wondering if anyone has had to do this in the past.

Comment: Please edit the answers to the following questions into your question above: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? How are you getting the token? Does [`signInWithCustomToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients) achieve what you are looking for? If not, why?

Answer (score 3):

Firestore SDKs have no concept of "headers".  It's also not possible to attach any extra data to a request using the SDK.

The Firesetore SDKs are only aware of the currently signed in user with the Firebase Auth SDK.  If you want to make a query with user credentials using a Firestore SDK, the user must be signed in using the Auth SDK.

If you can't use the Firebase Auth to sign in the user and you need to make requests authenticated for a user, your only option is to use the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api).  From the section on [Authentication and authorization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authentication_and_authorization):

> For authentication, the Cloud Firestore REST API accepts either a Firebase Authentication ID token or a Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token.